# How to show tooltip only for a particular hovering div which are dynamically generated

Tags: html, jquery, tooltip

I have the following `div`

```html
<div class="col-sm" title="Device Name" id="titleDevice" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><i class="fab fa-500px"></i> Name</div>
```

I am trying to show `tooltip` as below by pointing to the `id` of this element. This is working fine.

```js
showTooltip("#titleDevice");

function showTooltip(idOfElement) {
  $(idOfElement).hover(function() {
    $(idOfElement).tooltip('show');
  });
}
```

My issue is, in the page, sometimes there will be many such `div` which are dynamically generated. For that case, this selecting by `id` will not work and thus I tried selecting by `class`.

Example of such scenario with some number of `div` as below

```html
<form method="post" id="qaForm">
  <div class="card" style="background-color:white; color: white; position: relative; border-color: black; !important ">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm" title="Device Name" class="titleDevice" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><i class="fab fa-500px"></i> Name</div>

        <div class="col-sm" title="second" class="second" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><i class="fab fa-500px"></i> Second</div>

        <div class="col-sm" title="third" class="third" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><i class="fab fa-500px"></i>third</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
showTooltip(".titleDevice");

function showTooltip(classOfElement) {
  $(classOfElement).hover(function() {
    $(classOfElement).tooltip('show');
  });
}
```

Then used the same `JQuery` function. But when I hover over to one `div`, all the other div also showing the `tooltip` at the same time. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: can you show demo code for above ?

Comment: Can you add your complete code for the above issue , May be with 2 examples div's

Comment: @Swati Added some more codes as example

Comment: @Ajith Added an example of the scenario

Comment: No function needed here Try like this -> `$(document).on('hover', ".titleDevice", function() {
  $(this).tooltip('show');
});`   .

Comment: @Swati Sorry for the late reply. Probably the example I gave is not clear enough for my actual situation. I edited the example. There is a `form` called `qaForm` that contains many elements in it. All those elements needs to show respective `tooltips`. There are many such `qaForm` generated dynamically. I think because of the example I gave earlier was not clear, the code you provided is not working correctly. I changed the `form` id to class also. But still not working

Comment: check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/kpad90yz/) fiddle .You have not given class `titleDevice` to all your div maybe that the reason it doesn't work .

Comment: @Swati The fiddle you showed working perfectly. But somehow in my situation, it is not. However when I used `$(this).tooltip('show');` to my original `function` `showTooltip`, with a `class` to every `div`, it is showing correctly. But now the issue is, sometimes those `tooltips` remains there and not disappearing after I moved the cursor away. Basically the page reloads using `AJAX` on every 5 seconds. So I think during those Ajax call time, if I kept the cursor on those div, it is not disappearing even cursor moved away

Comment: the code where you have written ajax refresh there you can write code for hiding tooltip , or use some event handler i.e : [mouseout](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) to handle that .

Comment: @Swati I used the method as you said by adding codes to hide `tooltip` in `ajax` refresh. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the tooltip for only that particular element, use `this` keyword

```
showTooltip(".titleDevice");

function showTooltip(idOfElement) {
  $(idOfElement).hover(function() {
    $(this).tooltip('show');  // Use 'this' here
  });
}
```

Comment: Instead of `#titleDevice` you need to write `.titleDevice` op has used class selector.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want tooltip for dynamically generated `div` then use only

```
$(document).tooltip();
```

This will work for all `div`. You need not include the `hover method`.
You can preview below code:

```js
$(document).tooltip();

//for dynamically add
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(){

  $('#div').html('<div class="col-sm" title="Mobile Name"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><i class="fab fa-500px"></i> Name</div>');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">



<div class="col-sm" title="Device Name" id="titleDevice" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><i class="fab fa-500px"></i> Name</div>
<hr />
<button id="add">Add New</button>
<hr />
<div id="div"></div>
```